# From the Crystal Reports Navigate event using the page number, can you get the reportobjects on that page

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, reporting

I have a Main report that contains a number of subreports.  When I navigate in the main report from one page to another, I have access to "NavigateEventArgs e" which gives me the Page number in the main report. Given this page number, I would like to know which subreport is displayed on this page.

Has anyone any suggestions for obtaining this?

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer myself and it is something like this for anyone else interested:

private void CRViewer_Navigate(object source, CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.NavigateEventArgs e)
{

MessageBox.Show(((source as CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.PageView).GetActiveDocument().GetPage(e.NewPageNumber).SectionInstances[1].ReportObjectInstances[0].ObjectName.ToString()));

}